# Polygonizing global raster using Python/GDAL?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdalwarp, polygonize

I'm looking to polygonize a global raster with 29 different categories. However, when I try to run it in QGIS, it either crashes or takes forever to load.

I'm now trying to run it in python.

```
import subprocess, glob

script = "/usr/bin/gdal_polygonize.py"
for raster in glob.glob("/home/chiara/Desktop/WorldSoils/*.tif"):
    outshp = raster[:-4] + ".shp"
    subprocess.call(["python", script, raster, "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", outshp])
```

However, this still takes forever to load. Is there a way to polygonize on this raster by splitting up the earth into several grid cells (perhaps each about 6-degrees) and polygonizing each of those grid cells one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed split a raster into smaller tiles, but you will need to know the extents of each tile. **gdal_translate** and **-projwin** will give you the result you want.

Another solution, one I have used on large rasters, is to simplify/re-clasify the raster reducing its size. I have done this with **gdal_calc**, outputing a GeoTiff, **--type Byte**, with the following creation options **--co "NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS" --co "TILED=YES" --co "COMPRESS=LZW" --co "SPARSE_OK=TRUE"**, **--NoDataValue 00.000** and by simplifying the values to a range of values, in your case, 1 - 29. I have found that polygonizing these can be a lot quicker.